Do I really have to have my ISP's router?
My current situation is that I use a 4G router to ‘Harvest’ (if you like) the internet but wi-fi on this router is turned off. The internet is then fed via the ethernet port and switches around the house to p.c.’s, t.v.’s, entertainment units etc. via Cat 8 ethernet cabling. (Overkill on the Cat 8 I know but I’m trying to future proof).
There is a TP-Link repeater in the living room but it is in APM only and supplies 2.4GHz and 5GHz wi-fi for phones/tablets etc. I’m NOT a fan of wi-fi.
We intend to switch to fibre and the ISP is insisting that we need their router to provide a WAN before I can plug my LAN into their router.
I asked them if the ONT doesn’t do that and they won’t answer me citing that I need their router to do the ‘handshake’.
My research leads me to believe that this shouldn’t be the case as I won’t be using their router for wi-fi as it’ll be in a cupboard at the far end of the house next to the ONT.
I suppose my question is do you really need a router for this job or can the ONT not do this as my research has shown?

The ONT will indeed do the job at GPON level, providing you with an Ethernet-like connection to the ISP... but as with any other Ethernet-like connection (be it GPON or ADSL or real Ethernet in your flat), the ISP might not necessarily provide direct IP over that connection.
For example, some ISPs insist on using PPPoE, where the user's router (or PC) does an additional handshake over the Ethernet link that the ONT has established. And with PPPoE (almost exactly like with LTE), the device that performs the handshake is the device that "receives" the WAN IP address.
(Often the ONT has the necessary features, so perhaps it could set up PPPoE and do fake "pass-through" routing like LTE modems often do, although that would be a kind of routing – not anymore actual bridging that you may expect from an ONT.)
So if your ISP wants PPPoE, then either you'd need to find out the correct username & password (or worse: certificate) and set it up on your own router; most routers support that but extracting the information might be the hard part.
PPPoE was one possibility, but there could be various other requirements. Some ISPs merely require a VLAN ID (802.1Q tag) on the WAN port; not all routers support that. Some ISPs require a custom "class ID" in the DHCP lease request; even fewer routers support that. Some go wild and use 802.1X certificate authentication. Some don't require anything but really really want to see the "Customer device checked in and is OK" green indication in their dashboard.

Thank you for that very comprehensive answer. It IS slightly more complicated isn't it? I think I'll do what I normally do when the missus dictates and on this occasion do as I'm told and plug my ethernet lead into their router once installed. I'll go for the quiet life. Thank you once again.

In the UK at least, the authentication is by the ONT MAC address or serial number. A device such as https://www.fs.com/uk/products/133619.html is what many people use and you merely clone the details across. It would help if the op stated which country he resides in.

Sorry I live on Guernsey in the Channel Islands. A very closed market! :-(

Sure ... or Cable & Wireless is the provider I'm looking at.

I don't know if this will work. But in Europe we have a modem/router called fritz box. And can be a modem to the telco. It's of course popular.

FRITZ!Box is just a brand of modems popular in specific markets. The author doesn’t have that particular brand of modem.
